# Perl: do and eval result in different answers?

Tags: perl

I have a file with the following statements in it:

```
    {
        %{do '/tmp/personcontact.pl'},
        %{do '/tmp/address.pl'}
    }
```

Now, the temp files are as follows: 
Personcontact.pl :

```
            {
        'firstname' => {
            '__type' => 'String'
            },
        'lastname' =>  {
            '__type' => 'String'
            }
    }
```

Address.pl:

```
     {
        'address' => {
            'street' => {
                '__type' => 'String'
                },
            'unit' => {
                '__type' => 'String',
            },
            'suburb' => {
                '__type' => 'String'
            },
            '__type' => 'HASH'
        }
    }
```

Now, when I do :

```
    open(SCHEMAFILE, "<", $schema) or return undef; 
my $schemafile;     
while(my $line = <SCHEMAFILE>) { $schemafile .= $line;}
my $tempref = eval $schemafile;
print Dumper $tempref;
```

The result is `$VAR1 = '1/8'`

And when I do :

```
    print Dumper do "/tmp/schemawithinschema.pl";
```

The result is

```
                    $VAR1 = 'firstname';
        $VAR2 = {
            '__type' => 'String'
            };
        $VAR3 = 'address';
        $VAR4 = {
            'suburb' => {
                    '__type' => 'String'
                },
            'unit' => {
                '__type' => 'String'
                },
            'street' => {
                    '__type' => 'String'
                },
            '__type' => 'ARRAY'
            };
        $VAR5 = 'lastname';
        $VAR6 = {
            '__type' => 'String'
            };
```

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Hooooooooly cow.  The part where you're manually iterating over the (global!) filehandle SCHEMAFILE and then evaluating it is what I told you last time that is exactly what `do` does.  You're also ... just...  yeah. **cry**  Put this data into a JSON or YAML file instead, it will be 900x easier to maintain than this.

Comment: Agreed. Only Storable-based configs are worse in terms of maintainance. (I've even written a script that did a Storable->Dumper->vim->Dumper->Storable transform.)

Comment: I'm so tempted to mod down this question for crimes against sanity. Please don't do this.

Comment: @Sdaz I know, it looks horrible, feels horrible and I'm ashamed I'm doing it this way, but trust me I have no other options. I would much rather deal with JSON. My problem was that `do` and `eval` returned different things for the *same* string. Apparently, `do` doesn't like anonymous hashes. Thanks mate, hope you can feel my pain as well :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, to keep this from perpetuating forever, here is a module-based solution for you:

Foo.pm:

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    require Exporter;
    our @ISA = qw( Exporter );
    our @EXPORT_OK = qw( get_person get_address get_all );
    our $VERSION = '0.01';
}

my %person = (
    firstname => {
        __type => 'String',
    },
    lastname => {
        __type => 'String',
    },
);

my %address = (
    address => {
        street => {
            __type => 'String',
        },
        unit => {
            __type => 'String',
        },
        suburb => {
            __type => 'String',
        },
        __type => 'HASH',
    },
);

sub get_person
{
    return \%person;
}

sub get_address
{
    return \%address;
}

sub get_all
{
    return( { %person, %address } );
}

1;

__END__
```

bar.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '.';
use Foo qw( get_person get_address get_all );

my $junk = get_all();

print Dumper $junk;
```

But **really**, for the sake of your maintenance programmer (often yourself in 6 months), use [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.50/) or [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/YAML-0.72/) (or the faster [YAML::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/YAML-LibYAML-0.34/)), so that the data can be maintained as a simple-ish text file, instead of a series of nested data-disguised-as-code references.

To quote [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) (not sure if it was Damian originally):

> Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.

---

**EDIT**: For completeness, here is the equivalent solution using YAML (from CPAN):

data.yml:

```
---
firstname:
  __type: String
lastname:
  __type: String
address:
  __type: HASH
  street:
    __type: String
  suburb:
    __type: String
  unit:
    __type: String
```

baz.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use YAML qw( Load Dump LoadFile DumpFile );
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = LoadFile( 'data.yml' );
print Dumper $data;
```

Comment: Good write up, but my functioning JSON solution didn't prevent this question so I doubt your functioning YAML solution will help.

Comment: @daotoad Thanks guys! I realize I'm coding up something stupid here, but for the time being, I have to stick to Perl hashes in text files and evaluate them. I can clearly see how a YAML or JSON solution would end up being much more elegant. Thanks for taking the time to post answers. I can assure you that I'm not ignoring any advice you have given me, I just *have* to use perl hashes in this case, even though it might not seem right. Thanks again guys! :)

Answer (score 5):

One small pointer. That '1/8' is what you get when you evaluate a hash in a scalar context. The 8 is the number of buckets assigned to  the hash and the 1 is the number of buckets that are in use.

It's generally useless, other than as a flag that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

While the intent of the question makes me cry, the difference between your two code snippets has nothing to do with `do` or `eval` and everything to do with context.  And since that is a legitimate Perl topic, I'll briefly answer it.

In

```
my $tempref = eval $schemafile;
```

, the `eval` takes place in scalar context (imposed by the assignment to `$tempref`).  `$schemafile`, however, contains a hash, created by the hash reference dereference operator `%{}`.  When that hash is evaluated as a scalar it produces `1/8`, normal behavior for a hash.

In

```
print Dumper do "/tmp/schemawithinschema.pl";
```

, the `do` takes place in the list context imposed by the `Dumper` call (which in turn is in the list context of the `print`).  `do` creates the same hash that the `eval` did, but now it's being evaluated in list context, in fact as a list of arguments to `Dumper`.  The top-level hash gets flattened into a list of `Label => HashRef` pairs, but that's not enough to stop `Dumper` from being able to show you something that looks a lot like the hash you were trying to create.

For future reference, it is helpful when trying to pinpoint a strange difference of behavior to present exactly the same call in both cases.  The more variables between two test cases, the more things that you weren't expecting to matter will wind up mattering and confuse you.

All of that said, the real answer to "What's wrong here?" remains "Trying to do this at all.".